# VBS script runs manually, but not through scheduler

Tags: excel, vbscript, scheduled-tasks, vba

I have created a VBA script that sends an email of a graph when evoked. I am trying to set up a scheduled job to send out the email every day at 9:30 am.

I have created a VBS script that runs fine when I call it (i.e., cscript.exe EmailDailyBurnDown.VBS), but the script will not work when evoked via scheduler. Can you help?

**EmailDailyBurnDown.VBS**

```VBS
Dim ObjExcel, ObjWB
Set ObjExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set ObjWB = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\20170814_Promotion Work Backlog_V1.0.9.xlsm")
ObjExcel.Visible = False
ObjExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
ObjExcel.AskToUpdateLinks = False
ObjExcel.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False

'vbs opens a file specified by the path below
'either use the Workbook Open event (if macros are enabled), or Application.Run

ObjExcel.Application.Run "SendBurnDownChartViaEmail"
ObjWB.Save
ObjWB.Close
ObjExcel.Quit

Set ObjWB = Nothing
Set ObjExcel = Nothing
WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit
```

**VBA Script**

```vba
Sub SendBurnDownChartViaEmail()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim Fname As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    'File path/name of the gif file
    Fname = Environ$("temp") & "\My_Sales1.gif"

    'Save Chart named "Chart 1" as gif file
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Hidden").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.Export _
            Filename:=Fname, FilterName:="GIF"
    'MsgBox (Fname)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "akshay@xxxx.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "FBT Sprint " & Worksheets("5. Capacity & Sprint Planning").Range("E11").Value & " Burn Down - " & Date
        .Attachments.Add Fname
        .HTMLBody = "<html>" & "<img src='cid:My_Sales1.gif'></html>"
        .Send   'or use .Display
        '.Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Delete the gif file
    Kill Fname

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I get the following error. 
[image]
[image]
Thanks for your help!

Akshay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some googling brought up this result:
https://www.devhut.net/2014/10/31/createobjectoutlook-application-does-not-work-now-what/

The author does not state why it is the case that outlook automation won't work as seamlessly as it does with other MS Office software, but he provides an alternative way of binding an Outlook-instance, maybe this will solve your issue.

(Only a link, no code since the author explicitly says not to repost his code)